# In fastboot mode my phone appear locked

Tags: custom-roms, data-recovery, encryption, unbricking, ab-partition

My phone is Huawei mate 8 when i try to install a twrp is appear locked in fastboot mode & i cant unlock oem.
I cant acces to my data.
Any one have an idea about recovery data from fastboot mode.
Pleaaaaaaaase

Comment: you can unlock bootloader with PotatoNV but you can't decrypt your data without pattern